# Can emails senders deactivate gmail event creation?

Tags: email, events, calendar, gmail, schema

I would like to know if there is a way from an email sender side to specifically ask Gmail not to take into account an email while trying to generate an event.

This is because one of our emails sends information about an abandon purchase and it is currently automatically generating an event on the user's calendar. This generates a problem for the user because he does not actually has a reservation.

Comment: I am no sure, may be this link help for you ..

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/VnGG9gBDmWs;context-place=topicsearchin/calendar/authorid$3AAPn2wQfwKuZSHB77WgERQCaId3DghtA6YEmiYa_xFZTDOXfpedsPctTgSzFg5GP_pr-CQo7G5L9c%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false

Comment: Also this link 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/ufXkvelLigA

Comment: Hello, that is not exactly it because is has to be done by each user and i want to make this in the sender side. Thanks ayway